# How can I prevent database connections from timing out in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sidekiq

I have a Rails system in which every half hour, the following is done:

- There are 15 clients somewhere else on the network
- The server creates a record called `Measurement` for each of these clients
- The measurement records are configured, and then they are run asynchronously via Sidekiq, using `MeasurementWorker.perform_async(m.id)`
- The connection to the client is done with Celluloid actors and a WebSocket client
- Each measurement, when run, creates a number of event records that are stored in the database

The system has been running well with 5 clients, but now I am at 15, and many of the measurements don't run anymore when I start them at the same time, with the following error:

```
2015-02-04T07:30:10.410Z 35519 TID-owd4683iw MeasurementWorker JID-15f6b396ae9e3e3cb2ee3f66 INFO: fail: 5.001 sec
2015-02-04T07:30:10.412Z 35519 TID-owd4683iw WARN: {"retry"=>false, "queue"=>"default", "backtrace"=>true, "class"=>"MeasurementWorker", "ar
gs"=>[6504], "jid"=>"15f6b396ae9e3e3cb2ee3f66", "enqueued_at"=>1423035005.4078047}
2015-02-04T07:30:10.412Z 35519 TID-owd4683iw WARN: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)
2015-02-04T07:30:10.412Z 35519 TID-owd4683iw WARN: /home/webtv/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_
record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block in wait_poll'
....
```

Now, my production environment looks like this:

#### `config/sidekiq.yml`

```
production:
  :verbose: false
  :logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
  :poll_interval: 5
  :concurrency: 50
```

#### `config/unicorn.rb`

```
...
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 60
...
```

#### `config/database.yml`

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: ***
  username: ***
  password: ***
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: 50
```

#### `postgresql.conf`

```
max_connections = 100 # default
```

As you see, I've already increased the concurrency of Sidekiq to 50, to cater for a high number of possible concurrent measurements. I've set the database pool to 50, which already looks like overkill to me.

I should add that the server itself is quite powerful, with 8 GB RAM and a quad-core Xeon E5-2403 1.8 GHz.

What should these values ideally be set to? What formula can I use to calculate them? (E.g. *number of maximum DB connections = Unicorn workers × Sidekiq concurrency × N*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your pool configuration of 100 is not taking affect.  Each process will need a max of 50 so change 100 to 50.  I don't know if you are using Heroku but it is notoriously tough to configure the pool size.

Inside mysql, your max connection count should look like this:

```
((Unicorn processes) * 1) + ((sidekiq processes) * 50)
```

Unicorn is single threaded and never needs more than one connection unless you are spinning up your own threads in your Rails app for some reason.

Comment: I've switched to Postgres now, and the default is 100 max connections. According to your formula, 53 should be enough, assuming I only launch one Sidekiq process with a concurrency of 50? How does the pool value come into play here? Should `pool` always be lower or equal to `max_connections`, and therefore `sidekiq_concurrency * sidekiq_processes` also always lower than `pool` (and, consequently, `max_connections`)?

Comment: `pool` should be set to the max a **single process** will require, i.e. 50.  Connection pools are lazy so even if your Unicorn process pool setting is 50, it will only create one connection.

Comment: So, I've set PostgreSQL to 2000 maximum connections. I have a pool size of 100, and 3 Unicorn workers. One Sidekiq process with a concurrency of 50. Still, after some time (say, a day of measurements), the jobs fail with the same error, not getting a connection. Could it be that old connections do not properly get closed? What could I do to check and prevent that?

Comment: I would set up Postgres to close idle connections after N minutes.  It doesn't solve the problem but it might work around it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the creator of sidekiq @MikePerham is more than suited to the task of fixing your sidekiq issues but as a ruby dev two things stand out.

If you're doing a lot of database operations via ruby can you push some of them into the database as [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html)? You could still start them on the appside with a sidekiq process of course. :)

Second every half hour screams to me of a rake task run via cron. Hope you're doing that too. FWIW I usually use the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to create the cron line I have to drop into the crontab of the user running the app. Note its designed to autocreate the crontask in a scripted deploy but in a non-scripted one you can still leverage it to give you the lines you have to paste into your crontab though via the [*whenever*](https://github.com/javan/whenever#the-whenever-command) command.

Also you mention this is for measurements.

Have you considered leveraging something like [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/) and the [searchkick gem](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick)? This is a little more of a complex setup, be sure to firewall the server you install ES on. But this might make your code a lot more manageable as you grow. Also it gives you a good search mechanism almost for free and its distributed and more language agnostic, e.g. [Bloodhound](https://github.com/bitemyapp/bloodhound), [Java](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html). :) Plus [kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana) gives you a nice window into the ES records

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think triggers will help, as all database entries I create are pretty different. I already use whenever and IceCube to schedule measurement occurrences. I'm not sure how Elasticsearch would help me though. Sure, I could build a search engine into the app, but it's not a primary use case of what I'm doing.

Comment: basically [aggreations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).  Here is a [Nice Writeup](http://chrissimpson.co.uk/elasticsearch-aggregations-overview.html)  would allow you to use it similar to a graphite/statsd setup. not necessary if what you have is working though, just a thought.